# Удалить столбцы при соблюдении условия

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Мне необходимо записать файл на основе другого. В исходном файле есть значения 'ND' нужно исключить столбцы, где встречаются такие данные. Пробовал искать методом "np.isnan" он не находит все такие столбцы. Поэтому использую:

```
 qqq = np.sum(np.where(z1 == 'ND'))
    if (qqq > 0):
        count+=1
        #df.drop(df.columns[[j]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

но не получается удалить столбцы при помощи df.drop.
Файл с данными находится здесь [файл](https://dropmefiles.com/PToxN)

Весь код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('FRB.csv')
a = df.shape
count = 0
print("a=", a)
for j in range(0, a[1]):
    z1 = df.iloc[:, j].values
    qqq = np.sum(np.where(z1 == 'ND'))
    if (qqq > 0):
        count+=1
        #df.drop(df.columns[[j]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    print("j=", j, "qqq=", qqq, type(qqq), "len(z1)=", len(z1))

a = df.shape
print(count, "a=", a)
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать так: df.drop(df.columns[[j]], axis=1). Ошибок не возникает, но не удаляются колонки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно заменит данное значение на NaN

```
df = df.replace({'ND' : np.nan})
```

А затем удалить значения NaN

```
df.dropna(axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Нормальный вариант, тем более np.nan, тоже нужно исключить.

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [pd.read_csv(..., na_values=["ND"])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) - при помощи этого параметра можно и нужно указывать все значения (**дополнительно** к значениям по умолчанию: `‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘<NA>’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.`), которые должны восприниматься как `NaN`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("FRB.csv", header=None, na_values=["ND"]).dropna(axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [70]: df.shape
Out[70]: (372, 82)
```

Comment: Правильно ли понимаю, что в na_values можно вписать любое значение.  Или это касается только пустых значений?

Comment: @inquirer, при помощи этого параметра можно и нужно указывать все значения (__дополнительно__ к значениям по умолчанию: `‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘<NA>’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.`), которые должны восприниматься как `NaN`

Comment: Все теперь понял, что по умолчанию функция дополнительно ищет пробелы.

Comment: @inquirer, есть значения, которые `pd.read_csv()` __по умолчанию__ воспринимает как `NaN` (они указаны в ответе). Можно указать __дополнительные__  значения, которые тоже должны восприниматься как `NaN`